# Connect Microsoft Exchange to n8n

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, workflow, exchange-server, n8n

Hello my goal is to get exchange server data like:
email,firstname,lastname
and save in DB

For doing this i've read that i have to make this callback request:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/contacts
```

from microsoft graph and get the data in n8n workflow system

Answer (score 0):

> Hello my goal is to get exchange server data like: email,firstname,lastname

You need to clarify what data your after eg are you after a particular users personal contacts or are you after the whole organizations email details (eg similar to what you see in the Global Address List).

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/contacts
```

This will give you the current users personal contacts but if your after the organizations information then you use https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users or Org contacts you would use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/orgcontact-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Comment: When i execute this request, the output is:
"ResourceNotFound",
    "message": "Resource could not be discovered."
404 Not Found

Comment: You need to put some more detail in your question, which resource is not found /me ? if your using the client credentials authentication flow then there won't be a /me endpoint you need to specify a real user.  Having a code sample really helps with understand what you trying to do. If you not using the client credentials flow then the Graph Explorer is a good place to start https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer eg test if your creds and query work here first. Other thing like check the access token being used in jwt.io to a make sure you have the correct permissions

Comment: Hi @Glen, I want the list of my contact in exchange email, so I should use that request for taking all the data.

Comment: I'd suggest you start with the Graph explorer examples then you can learn at bit more about how the data works. Eg you can use the TryIt button in the docs to direct access that https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-contacts?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#code-try-3